# PHP XML append to created file

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have the following XML documment:

```
<list>
  <person>
     <name>Simple name</name>
  </person>
</list>
```

I try to read it, and basically create another "person" element. The output I want to achieve is:

```
<list>
  <person>
     <name>Simple name</name>
  </person>
  <person>
     <name>Simple name again</name>
  </person>
</list>
```

Here is how I am doing it:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('../test.xml');
$list = $xml->getElementsByTagName('list') ;

if ($list->length > 0) {
    $person = $xml->createElement("person");

    $name = $xml->createElement("name");        
    $name->nodeValue = 'Simple name again';

    $person->appendChild($name);
    $list->appendChild($person);
}

$xml->save("../test.xml");
```

What I am missing here?

**Edit:** I have translated the tags, so that example would be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're pointing/appending to the node list instead of that found parent node:

```
$list->appendChild($person);
// ^ DOMNodeList
```

You should point to the element:

```
$list->item(0)->appendChild($person);
```

Sidenote: The text can already put inside the second argument of `->createElement()`:

```
$name = $xml->createElement("name", 'Simple name again');
```

Comment: @user2917823 yeah, i got confused also on your revision, i also made the changes accordingly, glad this helped

Comment: Thanx for the text hint! Really helpful!